# How can I change class name in jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I change all class name a time in jquery.
thanks for helpful.
For Example:

```js
$('.myclass').removeClass("name-*");
$('.myclass').addClass("name-999");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass name-212"></div>
<div class="myclass name-545"></div>
<div class="myclass name-767"></div>
```

Comment: A better solution would be to avoid the problem entirely. Incremental `id` and `class` attributes are an anti-pattern - one reason why is what you're just discovered. Why do you need these classes at all?

Comment: id or class  it does not important. I need to that :)

Comment: I'm not saying to use ids or classes, I'm saying don't use incremental identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

try this one also:

```
$(".myclass").removeClass(function (index, className) {
   return (className.match (/(^|\s)name-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a regular expression

```
$('.myclass').removeClass(function (index, cssClass) {

  return (cssClass.match (/\bname-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');

});
```

It will remove all name- classes from .myclass.

But class names like that are not a good solution, maybe try explaining which problem you used this solution and we could give you a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you know/want the divs to have `myclass name-999` why don't you remove all the classes and add what you want ?

```js
$('.myclass').removeClass().addClass("myclass name-999");
```

```css
.name-999 {
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background:red;
  margin:10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass name-212"></div>
<div class="myclass name-545"></div>
<div class="myclass name-767"></div>
```